# Connecting external Java program with Apache via module

Tags: java, apache

Last time I think how can I connect my Java external program to Apache webserver.
I wanna send HTTP requests to process and then send output back as HTML file. 
I thought about JNI but with multi-thread structure, it doesn't look good for me.
I think with help of Sockets it could be nice but I want to hear Your ideas.
Last but very important: should I use "normal" Apache or Tomcat for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the level of integration you are looking for, JNI is way too low-level and involved.
Instead, take a look at:

- FastCGI: on the Apache side use `mod_fastcgi` and [jfastCGI](http://jfastcgi.org/) on the Java side.
- small HTTP servers: `mod_proxy` on the Apache side, which reverse proxies to a small HTTP server on the Java side such as [Netty](https://netty.io/) or [Undertow](http://undertow.io/).